is there a way of opening a reading a file in rust with root priveledges?
i am trying to read a file in the /dev directory on Linux using a rust program but i am not sure the program will always be ran as root,so i wish to know if there is a way of me giving permissions to file in my rust code and any other bypass
i tried using this little trick but unfornately for me is still say operation not permmitted
let perm_holder_file = fs::metadata("file_with_perm").unwrap().permissions();
fs::set_permissions("/dev/input", perm_holder_file).unwrap()



On linux you can use the setuid bit to run a binary with the privileges of the owning user. See the chmod man page for more info. Beware that this makes your program interesting for attackers trying to gain root on the system.

If your program doesn't have root permission, then there is no way for it to acquire that permission by itself. If any program could acquire root whenever it wanted, that would defeat the whole point of privilege separation.

I sure hope not.

thanks to you all @Jmb and others, i think i'll find another way then
